# VisualStudio 2015 Update 2 Xamarin unable to connect to Mac OSX

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin

After upgrading my Visual Studio to Update 2, I tried to do my first steps with Xamarin.
However I am unable to connect my MacBook.

This is my Setup:
MacBook Pro with OSX 10.11.3
Windows 10 Enterprise - newest updates installed
Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Update 2

Down below is the error I get when trying to connect my MacBook.

```
Starting Broker 4.0.3.214 in port 56182...
Couldn't connect to Maurices-MacBook-Pro.local. Please try again.
Disconnected from Mac Maurices-MacBook-Pro.local (192.168.2.164)
bash: /Users/maurice/Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA/Broker/4.0.3.214/Broker.exe: Permission denied
```

I did check, it created the folders and due to the permission denied error I did a chown for the user I use to login to the mac for the whole Xamarin directory
- did not help...

If someone could help me solve my little problem I would be happy.

Thanks in advance.

---

After changing the Channel to Alpha I get this:

```
Starting Broker 4.1.0.111 in port 54771...
Disconnected from Mac Maurices-MacBook-Pro.local (192.168.2.164)
Couldn't connect to Maurices-MacBook-Pro.local. Please try again.
Timeout für den Vorgang wurde überschritten.
Downloading /Users/maurice/Library/Logs/Xamarin-4.1/2016-04-01__01-16-08.10484.Broker.stderr.log...

Xamarin.Messaging.VisualStudio.MessagingService Information: 0 : [2016-04-01 01:21:18.4551] Starting Broker 4.1.0.111 in port 55014...
Xamarin.Messaging.Client.Ssh.SshCommands Error: 0 : [2016-04-01 01:21:19.3288] mono cannot be found.
```

It is nowhere written that I have to have mono on my mac ...

---

After installing mono I received this error ...

```
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Messaging.State.ServerStateContext Information: 0 : [2016-04-01 03:19:54.9773] MacServer State transition from DisconnectedState to SshConnectingState on Maurices-MacBook-Pro.local (192.168.2.164)
Xamarin.Messaging.VisualStudio.MessagingService Information: 0 : [2016-04-01 03:20:05.7313] Starting Broker 4.1.0.111 in port 58821...
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Messaging.State.ServerStateContext Information: 0 : [2016-04-01 03:20:12.0435] MacServer State transition from SshConnectingState to DisconnectedState on Maurices-MacBook-Pro.local (192.168.2.164)
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Messaging.State.ServerStateContext Information: 0 : [2016-04-01 03:20:12.0485] Disconnected from Mac Maurices-MacBook-Pro.local (192.168.2.164)
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Messaging.State.DisconnectedState Error: 0 : [2016-04-01 03:20:12.1445] Couldn't connect to Maurices-MacBook-Pro.local. Please try again.
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Messaging.State.DisconnectedState Error: 0 : [2016-04-01 03:20:12.1505] Xamarin.Messaging.Broker.BrokerServer Information: 0 : Starting broker...

Xamarin.Messaging.Broker.BrokerAgent Information: 0 : Starting Agent: Broker 4.1.0.111 (PID=1963)
Xamarin.Messaging.Broker.BrokerAgent Information: 0 : Broker 4.1.0.111 agent started
Failed-Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1

Xamarin.Messaging.Exceptions.MessagingException: Xamarin.Messaging.Broker.BrokerServer Information: 0 : Starting broker...
Xamarin.Messaging.Broker.BrokerAgent Information: 0 : Starting Agent: Broker 4.1.0.111 (PID=1963)
Xamarin.Messaging.Broker.BrokerAgent Information: 0 : Broker 4.1.0.111 agent started
Failed-Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1
```

Comment: I got exactly the same and stuck there too)

Comment: hmm, I have no clue, google doesnt either :(

Comment: as option, you could try to download and install the xamarin for Mac, however it must work out of the box without any aditional tweaks)

Comment: Yea your right, config steps in VS 2015 Update2 only explained that you needed to enable remote logins ... and then it didnt work

Comment: Have you gone through the troubleshooting documentation? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting/

Comment: I installed xamarin for Mac, changed update channel to alpha in xamarin studio and updated xamarin. After these manipulations ios build from visual studio started to work. This approach not very handy because it downloads a lot of files and requires installation xamarin on both platforms.

Comment: yea that troubleshooting isnt working out, every single step describled there is working except mono ...

Comment: I have installed xamarin for mac, changed update channel to beta and updated xamarin studio from 5.x to 6.x. Can login with ssh. Alpha seems to require other license so beta is better.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Xamarin for Visual Studio** doesn't install some requirements on the Mac side like Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Mac and Mono. All of those are requirements that are installed by the **Xamarin Studio installer on the Mac** (from http://xamarin.com/download). You should hit that URL from the Mac itself to get the Mac download, otherwise you'll see the Windows download.

As mentioned before, you will also need to configure "Remote Login" on the Mac. And additionally, you need an open session on the Mac with the same credentials you're using from Windows to connect. On other words, if you're using a 'User1' on the Mac, that User1 should be logged in on the Mac, and those Mac credentials will be the ones Visual Studio is asking for when it tries to connect.

For more help please take a look at the [troubleshooting guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting/).

Finally, if you're still facing issues connecting to your Mac, please share the logs (Help - Xamarin - Zip Logs). That includes diagnostic information that can be very helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Just to add to this too, you'll also want to use either the latest beta or stable channel to take advantage of using a Visual Studio license for Xamarin, the Alpha channel still requires a Xamarin license until that gets updated sometime next week.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing to the "Alpha Channel" must be changed in Visual Studio and Xamarin study and update all

Comment: thanks, that helped for the first part, I updated my question, maybe you got a clue ...

Comment: After trying everything, the only thing that worked was changing the updates to alpha, after update Both Visual Studio Xamarin and Mac Xamarin Studio it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Most of these issues usually go away if you install Xamarin Studio on the Mac you wish to use as your build/iPhone simulator host (from http://xamarin.com/download). It bundles "all the things".

That installer includes Mono, among other things. Also make sure you enable remote login on the mac (ssh) for the user you wish to connect with (which is in the "Sharing" control panel for some interesting Apple-y reason).

Answer (score 2):

The problem that I discovered (thanks to the one who wrote about the logs) was that Xamarin Build Agent, while trying to connect to the Build Host, failed when reading the .bashrc file.

It came down to that I had the line "source dnvm.sh" and that dnvm.sh no longer exists on my system. That made the program crash when the script was being executed.

So check the logs!

Answer (score 1):

To solve *mono cannot be found* you could download mono from here:

http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-mac

Updated: try to install xamarin on Mac, change update channel to alpha in xamarin studio and update xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

I run OSX on a local VM on my Windows 10 machine. This set up has worked well the past few months until this morning. Yesterday I updated Xamarin in Visual Studio 2015 and on my OSX instance. Then I continued working all day.

This morning I could not connect to my Mac Agent. So I started troubleshooting the problem.
1.Connected to the MacMini I have on the network fine. So, The issue is on my VM version of OSX.
2.Can SSH to the VM
3.Check the logs and see the problem is a hung broker on my OSX instance.
4.Deleted the XMA Folder on OSX and forced it to regenerate.

Issue fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem.
 If your Visual studio has a open xamarin solution, then u are changing some proxy or network settings.
 the Mac agent doesn't get the latest settings.
 so answer is
 close VS 2013 or 2015, make the network / proxy changes in IE
 Open VS and open the Xamarin solution again..
 wao the mac agent works like a charm and auto connects to Mac